# How can I exclude the last regex match check on this regex?

Tags: json, regex

How can I match the comma between each key:value pair EXCEPT to exclude the last comma match? And please me know if you have a cleaner regex as mine seems a little messy. I am new to writing regex.

I need to pattern match this format and they need to be map string:string
{\"key1\":\"val1\",....N}
or
{"key1":"val1",....N}

Example

{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\",\"k3\":\"v3\",\"k4\":\"v4\"}

What I have for my regex:

```
^[{]((["]|[\\]["])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(["]|[\\]["])[:](["]|[\\]["])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(["]|[\\]["])[,])+[}]$
```

What my match is - I do not want the last comma:
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"**,**}

Answer (score 1):

Its usually done by requiring the first Key/Val pair, then making all the others
optional with a prepended separator `,`

```
^{\\?"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\?":\\?"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\?"(?:,\\?"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\?":\\?"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\?")*}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/cqJk8q/1

```
 ^ 
 {
 \\? " [a-zA-Z0-9]+ \\? ": \\? " [a-zA-Z0-9]+ \\? "
 (?:
    , \\? " [a-zA-Z0-9]+ \\? ": \\? " [a-zA-Z0-9]+ \\? "
 )*
 }
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ending with

```
[,])+[}]$
```

end with

```
(,(?!$)|}$))+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/B9nm8wcBWVgKmP).

Also, some simplification you can do:

- `[:]` is identical to just `:`, etc for all like this
- `(["]|[\\]["])` is identical to `\\?"`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is *almost* equivalent to `\w` (`\w` also allows the underscore - if that's a problem, just leave `[a-zA-Z0-9]`)

So, your whole regex could be refactored to:

```
^\{(\\?"\w+\\?":\\?"\w+\\?"(,(?!$)|}$))+$
```

Your regex however allow mismatched escaping, eg

```
`{\"key1": "value1"}`
`{"key1": "value1\"}`
```

To fix that, capture the optional backslash and use a back reference to it on the other end so they must be balanced:

```
^\{(?:(\\?)"\w+\1":(\\?)"\w+\2?"(,(?!$)|}$))+$
```

See [live demo (with all input varieties)](https://rubular.com/r/cAAOTYf9X5HXle).

To also restrict input to either all quotes escaped *or* no quotes escaped, add negative look ahead anchored to start `(?!.*\\".*[^\\]"|.*[^\\]".*\\")`, which is one type then the other or visa versa:

```
^(?!.*\\".*[^\\]"|.*[^\\]".*\\")\{(?:\\?"\w+\\?":\\?"\w+\\?"(,(?!$)|}$))+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/dpMMIDeQyQ7IBy).

The previous back reference based check for balanced escaping for a key/value pair has been removed because the look ahead now enforces balanced quoting.

Comment: Your solution allows Key/Val pairs to be separated by a `}` too.

Comment: @sin yes - I've just added some text about that.

Comment: @sin but OP's regex also allows mismatched escaped and unescaped quotes, so there are already gaps

Comment: Could be the guts don't matter to him. Seems he is very interested in the separator. He may have his reasons, but his focus for now is on the `,` separator.

Comment: @sin I just realized how to fix the `}` between k/v pairs problem: `(,|}$))+$` :)

Comment: Close but that matches {K/V,.., https://rubular.com/r/dBBHRFFBZykBfe Maybe `(,(?!$)|}$))+$`

Comment: @sin great pickup. Added in. Thanks for the discussion - good result.

Comment: Yeah I guess I wouldn’t want to mix escaped and non escaped “, either or is better.

Comment: @kalbo123 do you mean *everything* should be escaped, or *everything* unescaped? I could make it the each key/value pair should be all escaped or all unescaped, eg `{"key":"value",\"key\":\"value\"}` would pass, but I can't do a global check.

Comment: @Bohemian. yeah I need everything escaped or everything unescaped. {"key":"value",\"key\":\"value\"} shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @kalbo123 see final version added to only match if all escaped or none escaped.